Istio ambient mode connection to ipv4 endpoint
I have ipv6 only EKS cluster and istio service mesh with sidecar proxy containers. In this setup i can connect directly ipv4 endpoint e.g. curl -v -4 https://sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, this flag gives this possibility: ISTIO_ENABLE_IPV4_OUTBOUND_LISTENER_FOR_IPV6_CLUSTERS = true. I have recently upgraded istio to version 1.23.2 and switched to ambient mode. Using ambient mode this curl command returns:
* Host sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 54.239.54.197
*   Trying 54.239.54.197:443...
* Connected to sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com (54.239.54.197) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 
* closing connection #0
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer


Is it possible to connect directly to ipv4 endpoint using istio ambient mesh?

It is a bug which will be fixed in version 1.24.
https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/53483

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
